# python WMI screen brightness adjuster gets error 0x8004100c

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, screen-brightness

I'm currently working on a script that creates a tray icon that allows the user to adjust screen brightness through menu options. The source code, written in python 3.6.8, can be found as a paste [HERE](https://pastebin.com/sLbyE9yb). There seems to be an error message coming up when trying to select one of the brightness options, seen [HERE](https://pastebin.com/Xs7wHk73). I did some reading and found that the error I'm getting ([0x8004100c](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-error-constants)) refers to a feature or operation not being supported. Are there any workarounds available for this?

Thank you in advance.

code: https://pastebin.com/sLbyE9yb

error: https://pastebin.com/Xs7wHk73

WMI error reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-error-constants

gist: https://gist.github.com/imri0t/12e768e3d7e08734b85ae532d56090e1

(also if anyone can let me know if there's a way to keep the script from dying after an action is made it would be appreciated)

modules needed: pip install infi.systray / pip install wmi

code snip that I believe produces the error:

```
from infi.systray import SysTrayIcon
import wmi

def brightness_50(systray):
    '''brightness: 50%'''
    b = 50
    c = wmi.WMI(namespace='root\\wmi')

    br = c.WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods()[0]
    br.WmiSetBrightness(3, b) #b will be a precentage / 100


menu = (("brightness: 100%", None, brightness_50))

systray = SysTrayIcon("icon.ico", "brightness", menu)

systray.start()
```